# How to add styles to part of a body text in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to highlight a certain body string. So if there is an `@` @username highlight part of the string, and leave the rest of the content unhighlighted. Very similar to how discord mentions a user.

So im trying to implement that logic

**The issue is that it's highlighting the wrong parts of the string.** For example

[image]

```
const regex = /^@/i;
const words = comment.comment_body.split(" ");
let highLight;
let username;
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    const word = words[i];
    console.log("checking for word", word);
    if (regex.test(word)) {
        username = word
        console.log("test passed");
        highLight = <ReactMarkdown className="highlightMention" source={word} />;
    } else {
        highLight = <ReactMarkdown className="markdownStyle" source={comment.comment_body} />;
    }
}


.....
{comment.gifUrl === "" && highLight}
```

Comment: can't see your pic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the splitted workds and if that words starts with `@` return it inside the highlighter else return the normal word :

```
const Component = () => {
    ...
      return <div>{ comment.comment_body.split(' ').map(word=>{
           if(word.startsWith('@')){
            return <ReactMarkdown className="highlightMention" source={body} />; 
            }else{
            return " "+word ;
        }
       })}
    </div>;
    };
```

Comment: I have to use `<ReactMarkdown className="markdownStyle" source={comment.comment_body} />;` if its a normal word how should i handle this use case ?

Comment: in else block return `<ReactMarkdown className="markdownStyle" source={" "+word} />`

Comment: Where is `str` being used ?

Comment: this works but it adds a new line for each `str` element

Comment: `str` it's `word` ,i think the added line is probably caused by that component

Answer (score 0):

```
const regex = /^@/i;
const words = comment.comment_body.split(" ");
let highLight = [];
let username;
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    const word = words[i];
    console.log("checking for word", word);
    if (regex.test(word)) {
        username = word
        console.log("test passed");
        // `highLight = <ReactMarkdown className="highlightMention" source={word} />;` this line will only do `highlight` for the last `word`
        highLight.push(<ReactMarkdown className="highlightMention" source={word} />);
    } else {
        highLight.push(<ReactMarkdown className="markdownStyle" source={comment.comment_body} />);
    }
}


.....
{comment.gifUrl === "" && highLight}
```

Comment: yes. React 16.x start support it. `React` support return an array

Comment: im using typescript and im getting  `Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.  TS2345`
[0]

Comment: i fixed it, let me try it now.

Comment: this creates duplicate content.

Comment: actually. I can't see your pic. so I have no idea about your `words ` content

Comment: this pic is down for me. so would you mind to show the word content by text

Comment: ill try to work with the current answers, and see what the issue is.

Comment: i had to add `word` to the else statement

Comment: its not really solved, for every word it makes a new line with either a mentioned username or non mentioned comment, everything should be in one paragragh, so im trying to fix it. Not really sure

Comment: ill share a pic

Comment: Im sorry about my network. I still can't open the image link

Comment: oh..... well pretty much its doing something like this @barnowl(new line)
                                                                                      word(new line)
                                                                                      word (new line)
it does this for each line, when it should be in one line.